# Non linear Sankey graph : Any tools accepted

Tags: d3.js, graph, charts, sankey-diagram, geography

I'm trying to make sankey graph like this :
[This one](https://i.pinimg.com/1200x/7a/d8/d6/7ad8d63bec9cb9716cccc839a081e42d.jpg)
[Or this one](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/b9/25/bcb9259331f8e839215479d10ed939d1.jpg)
(Sorry, not enough reputation for the image)

It's possible to [use Tikz](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/sankey-diagram/) but not really adequate for curved lines.
I imagined doing it by hand, but even [drawing two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258806/how-to-draw-two-lines-side-by-side-with-tikz) side by side doesn't seem easy in Tikz.

Does anyone know of a technology that can plot a Sankey diagram based on vertex positions and the flow of connecting edges?

Comment: What do you mean by "make".  Do you want  a)  a tool to draw the graph using input of of vertices, edges and edge weights or b) construct the vertices, edges and edge weights  from the images you posted?  ( Note that asking for tool recommendations is disallowed on stackoverflow - perhaps you forgot to read "how to ask a good question"?

Comment: I've just clarified the question, it would be your point (a) to draw a map as shown in the example.